# Older iPhone/ iPod frame rate?

Tags: iphone, ipod, frame-rate

Do older iPods and iPhones have a frame rate of 60fps?
I'm finding that all the methods for calculating time intervals on iPhone (cftimeinterval, nstimer, timesince1970, etc) are all giving me bad data, so I've decided assume a frame rate of 60, just not sure if older apple devices can run at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame rate is limited by the hardware to 60 fps in the older iPhones/iPods as well. Of course it depends on your application wether or not it can run 60 frames per second.